# Why branch-and-bound is approximate and not exact?

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem, approximation, branch-and-bound

I have read that branch-and-bound paradigm is approximate. Can someone explain why this method is approximate and not exact? what it means that it's approximation? I implemented it for knapsack problem and always when I run this algorithm, it gives me exact answer.

Comment: If you process all branches, the paradigm delivers the exact result.

Comment: *"I have read that..."*: please provide your source, and quote it.

Comment: I do not remember the source. it's not like this?